# Preposition after 'student assistant' in CV

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What preposition would I use on my CV, for example, when I want to state that I am a student assistant with/at/of/_ the XYZ-Project (University of XYZ)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd add 'working'; 'working on/with ...'.

Comment: *With*, *on*, *for*, *to*, or *at* are all possible, although *at* implies a specific location, and *to* might be more common *to a person* (despite NGrams showing "assistant to" is the most common). I'm not sure there are strong grounds for preferring one.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear whether "attached to" is a preposition alongside other two-word prepositions such as "*according to*", "*next to*", or "*contrary to*", but it is a usual enough combination of words used in the context of association of people with organizations of all sorts when one does not choose to specify any particular process of association (appointment, election, and other processes of selection).

[Introduction to Project Management: A Source Book for ... Davies A. Igberaese · 2022](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Introduction_to_Project_Management/uzh7EAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22attached+to+the+project%22&pg=PT221&printsec=frontcover) This method insures that highly competent human resources are attached to the project as may be considered appropriate.

[Decisions and Orders of the National Labor Relations Board
United States. National Labor Relations Board · 1955](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Decisions_and_Orders_of_the_National_Lab/1TbGAAAAMAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22attached+to+the+project%22&pg=PA1269&printsec=frontcover) Each of these meetings was attended by Francis H. Bacon, chief of the industrial branch of the project, and Frederick Rutt, Jr., a labor relation specialist attached to the project also attended some of the meetings.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, *on* is a common preposition when describing roles of members of a project.

> Student assistant on the XYZ Project at the University of ABC

Also acceptable would be "in the XYZ Project team".